# How can I use elasticsearch with the data on ms sql?

Tags: elasticsearch

my data is on Sql server and I want to use ElasticSearch.

Does ElasticSearch mean that there will also be a copy of the data?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Elasticsearch and SQL is totally independent databases and there is no relation in them**. ms sql is relational database while Elasticsearch is search database which is document based.

People uses RDBMS as source of truth and build Elasticsearch to serve the search and analytics application and **it all depends on you how you want to populate your elasticsearch and keep the data in your SQL and Elasticsearch.**

1. You can have Elasticsearch without any backing RDBMS.
2. You can have both and choose to delete data from SQL once copied to Elasticsearch or have the data in both databases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I was thinking of Elasticsearch as a search engine.
Now I am learning that there is a database. I am already using MongoDB. Should I use elasticsearch for speed dials?